# Sitecore 7.5 :Single Sign On (SSO) with Azure AD

Tags: azure, sitecore, single-sign-on, sitecore7, sitecore7.5

Context: We are developing around 20000 microsites in Sitecore with each site having 10-20 pages at max or may be less than that.We have an existing admin portal which uses Azure AD for authentication.Admins managing the portal will be managing these microsites as well.So we will have to implement SSO for these admins so that once they are logged in to the portal ,they should be automatically logged in to sitecore as well and manage the site.

Hence I am trying to integrate Azure AD with sitecore.

Problem: 
I don't see any blog or link implementing the same .So any insights can help me in implementing Azure AD with sitecore.I am also wondering how we can manage various roles that are present in sitecore and assign to these users authenticated from azure AD as well.

Thanks In Advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box support to Azure AD in Sitecore 7.5.

Answer (score 0):

you can look into Active Directory 1.2 Module to achieve it... https://dev.sitecore.net/en/Downloads/Active_Directory/1_0/Active_Directory_1_2.aspx